# Is $(P, \circ)$, with $p(x) \circ q(x) = p'(x) + q'(x)$, a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$?

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, group-theory, vector-spaces

I was requested to evaluate whether $(P, \circ)$ is a vector space over $\mathbb{R}$, with $P$ the set of all polynomials with real coefficients and $p(x)\circ q(x)=p'(x)+q'(x)$ (derivative addition). The approach I took was to prove $(P, \circ)$ is not an abelian group due to the absence of a unique neutral (or identity) element for $\circ$. However, I have a particular question regarding my demonstration. Firstly, this is what I did.

---

$\text{Assume : } !\exists p(x), \forall q(x)|p(x) \circ q(x)=q(x), \text{ with } q(x), p(x) \in P$.

If we let $q(x)=x$ it follows from the assumption and the definition of $\circ$ that

$$
q'(x) + p'(x)=q(x) \iff 1+ p'(x) = x \iff p(x)= \int x-1 \space dx\iff p(x)=\frac{x^2}{2}-x
$$

For $q(x)=x^2$  we similarly find

$$
q'(x) + p'(x)=q(x) \iff 2x+ p'(x) = x^2 \iff p(x)= \int x^2-2x\space dx
$$

which means $p(x)=\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2$.

But this is a contradiction, since $p(x)$ is presumed to be unique and $\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2 \neq \frac{x^2}{2}-x$. Then there is not a unique polynomial $p(x)$ such that $\forall q(x) \in P|q(x) \circ p(x)=q(x)$.

---

My question is whether any particular detail should be paid to the fact that $\frac{x^3}{3}-x^2 = \frac{x^2}{2}-x$ for some values of $x$ (e.g. $x=0$). Since when we evaluate any polynomial at a definite point $x$ it ceases to be a polynomial and "becomes" (or is a mapping to) a real number, I think this detail is of no relevance to the properties of $P$. However, I don't want to be misinterpreting anything since I'm very new to algebra.

Comment: It's not a problem if the polynomials are equal at particular points - equality in this vector space means the polynomials must identical for all $x$. However, you forgot to include constants of integration. Once you adjust for that, your proof is fine.

Comment: Have a look at associativity. Also, the fact that the neutral element isn't unique is suspicious.

Comment: Your proof is fine. As a shorter alternative, note $\deg (p \circ q) =\max(\deg(p) - 1,\deg(q)-1)$, so if $q$ is some fixed identity element then for $p$ with degree higher than $\deg q$ the operation must reduce degree, a contradiction.

Comment: @BrevanEllefsen Far more elegant. Thanks to everybody!